# Workflow build precedence

Tags: jenkins-workflow

What is the expected behavior when one build surpasses another while the former one is paused? If I have a workflow job with 2 stages and I have run 2 builds on it, and build #1 is paused in stage 1 (e.g. maybe someone just forgot to abort it) but build #2 is already on or past stage 2, is it desirable that build #1 should abort? Presumably we wouldn't want that one to continue if the last step is, say, Deploy To Production, otherwise it may well overwrite build #2 running in production, which is actually the one we want. Looking for some insight on how we're expected to handle this situation , or how others already have, as there are a number of ways to address it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for [JENKINS-27039](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27039).